# When using Android Eclipse WYSIWYG, with a RelativeLayout, how do I fine tune positioning

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically, I want to, say, move a TextView further/closer to another view object but not using the Drag and Move facility which is too coarse. Would like to fine tune positioning, one px or dp at a time using arrow keys or something similar.

If I can't get the exact positioning with the mouse, I have to go and edit the XML.

Basically, is there any possibility of "1 unit at a time" movement of objects within the Graphical layout Editor in Eclipse.

Comment: Why you don't go to the xml and increase or decrease the values as you need?

Comment: This I can do but it is such a shame one cannot use the arrow keys to move, especially in a Linearlayout, and have Eclipse update the corresponding View Property. I'm used to this in other GUI designers and simply assumed I'd simply not found the secret of how to do this